# C# process IAsyncEnumerable items with several parallel tasks in asp.net core hosted service consumer

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, producer-consumer, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm implementing producer-consumer in asp.net core app using hosted service. I was able to get it working to a point where consumer is processing items from `_recordProcessingChannel.ReadAllAsync()` synchronously.

I'm trying to split result of `_recordProcessingChannel.ReadAllAsync()` into several parallel tasks.
For ex.: I have 10000 items read from channel and i want to split this work into 4 seperate tasks and process 2500 items per ICMService.

consumer:

```
await foreach (var record in _recordProcessingChannel.ReadAllAsync())
{

    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var processor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICMService>();

    processor.UploadRecord(record);
                
}
```

reader:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<RecordData> ReadAllAsync(CancellationToken ct = default) => _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(ct);
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided

Comment: Do you want to buffer locally the 10,000 items, and after they have all been received to split them into 4 chunks and send each chunk for processing to a separate ICMService, or you want to send each individual item to a ICMService at the exact moment it's received? In the second case, do you want to alternate ICMService so that exactly 2,500 items are sent to each one, or perform load balancing and send more items to the faster responding ICMService's?

Comment: First option. Message bundles will be coming to channel  as users post their requests, so it will be 10000 at one go, after some time another 8000, then another 12000. I want to load balance those chunks, so when 10000 comes each service instance will handle ~ 2500, then when 8000 comes each will do ~2000 etc.

Comment: What are the criteria for the batch-size being one time 10,000, another time 8,000, and another time 12,000? Do you want to trigger the batching based on elapsed interval instead of size? Also is it acceptable to add a dependency to an external library, and specifically the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start needed number of processing tasks and use [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) to `enqueue` work. Something like this:

```
// my dummy async enumerable
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> ReadAllAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        yield return i*3 + 1;
        yield return i*3 + 2;
        yield return i*3 + 3;
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
    yield return 777;
}
var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>();
// start "processors"
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(i => 
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!collection.IsCompleted)
            {           
                int? data = null;
                try
                {
                    data = collection.Take();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

                if (data != null)
                {
                    // simulate processing 
                    Thread.Sleep(400);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.Value);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No more items to take.");
        }))
    .ToArray();

await foreach (var record in ReadAllAsync())
{
    collection.Add(record);
}
collection.CompleteAdding(); // signal that enqueuing has finished

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This can be improved introducing some async signaling (with `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` or [`AsyncManualResetEvent.WaitAsync`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncManualResetEvent) for example) so the consumer threads will not consume CPU while waiting for new items. For example:

```
var collection = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 4);
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // to signal that queueing is completed
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(i => 
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested && !collection.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No more items to take.");
                    break;
                }
                else if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await semaphore.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        //ignore
                    }
                }

                if(collection.TryDequeue(out var data))
                {
                    //simulate work
                    Thread.Sleep(400);
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                }                   
            }
        }))
    .ToArray();

await foreach (var record in ReadAllAsync())
{
    collection.Enqueue(record);
    semaphore.Release();
}
cts.Cancel(); // addition completed.
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("end");
```